# Return page for WooCommerce 2.5.5 custom payment gateway?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom payment gateway for WooCommerce that will redirect the payer to the third party site to make the payment, then get send back to the merchant site. What would be the best return URL, we should use? I would like to be able to wire up the handler that will extract querystring params and do some validation before update the status and return proper message on that page.

I'm currently using .../checkout/order-received, then add the method on the constructor to look for certain querystring params to determine if the system need to update the order status or not. Is that a right practice? Is there a way for me to add addtional text to the screen on that page?  In the past we use to be able to wire add_action('init', array($this,'some_handler_method')); but that doesn't seem to trigger anymore in the new WooCommerce version.

I already have the call back handler via Woocommerce API that will also update the order as the back up as well, but I would like to have the return page as a primary way to update the order status.

Thank you,

Comment: For whatever reason, commenting `ob_start()` in file `plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-api.php` restores the expected behavior. No idea why... maybe you should fill a bug.

Comment: Well, actually, the callback function does trigger, however the output won't print out unless you explicitly call `ob_flush()`.